# Does printf only allow taking a string literal as the first argument?

Tags: c, printf

According to the definition of `printf`, it says that first argument should be an array i.e `char*` followed by ellipses `...` i.e variable arguments after that.  If I write:

```
printf(3+"helloWorld"); //Output is "loWorld"`
```

According to the definition shouldn't it give an error?

Here is the definition of `printf`:

```
#include <libioP.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#undef printf

/* Write formatted output to stdout from the format string FORMAT. */
/* VARARGS1 */
int __printf(const char *format, ...) {
    va_list arg;
    int done;

    va_start(arg, format);
    done = vfprintf(stdout, format, arg);
    va_end (arg);

    return done;
 }

 #undef _IO_printf
 ldbl_strong_alias(__printf, printf);
 /* This is for libg++.  */
 ldbl_strong_alias(__printf, _IO_printf);
```

Comment: Arrays are passed to functions as pointers. A pointer plus an integer is a pointer, so `3 + "hello"` is a perfectly valid pointer.

Comment: The first argument in the printf style functions is used for specifying the rest of the arguments, you don't have to have additional arguments and in that case its just a string.  Your example is perfectly valid as you are just supplying an offset into a string.

Comment: The compiler simply interpret the argument `3+"HelloWorld"` for what it is **an expression**, compute it using pointers arithmetic and pass to `printf` a pointer that points 3 chars ahead in the buffer.

Comment: Not mentioned yet but many consider it *good practice* to only use a string literal as the format string. This allows compile-time detection of incorrect format specifiers (which cause undefined behaviour as runtime). Modern versions of gcc can warn with `-Wformat-nonliteral` and `-Wformat=2` and similar flags

Answer (score 22):

This is not an error.

If you pass `"helloWorld"` to `printf`, the string literal is converted to a pointer to the first character.

If you pass `3+"helloWorld"`, you're adding 3 to a pointer to the first character, which results in a pointer to the 4<sup>th</sup> character.  This is still a valid pointer to a string, it's just not the whole string that was defined.

Answer (score 10):

`3+"helloWorld"` is of `char *` type (after conversion in call to `printf`). In C, the type of a string literal is `char []`. When passed as an argument to a function, `char []` will convert to pointer to its first element (array to pointer conversion rule). Therefore, `"helloWorld"` will be converted to a pointer to the element `h` and `3+"helloWorld"` will move the pointer to the 4<sup>th</sup> element of the array `"helloWorld"`.

Answer (score 3):

From [Pointer Arithmetic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic):

> If the pointer P points at an element of an array with index I, then
>
> > P+N and N+P are **pointers** that point at an element of the same array with index I+N
> > P-N is a **pointer** that points at an element of the same array with index {tt|I-N}}
>
> The behavior is defined only if both the original pointer and the result pointer are pointing at elements of the same array or one past the end of that array. ....

The type of string literal is `char[N]`, where `N` is size of string (including null terminator).

From C Standard#6.3.2.1p3 *[emphasis mine]*

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an expression that has type ''array of type'' is converted to an expression with type ''pointer to type'' that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue**. If the array object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

So, in the expression

```
3+"helloWorld"
```

`"helloWorld"`, which is of type `char [11]` (array of characters), convert to *pointer to character* that points to the initial element of the array object.

Which means, the expression is:

```
3 + P
where P is pointer to initial element of "helloWorld" string

  ----------------------------------------------
  | h | e | l | l | o | W | o | r | l | d | \0 |
  ----------------------------------------------
    ^
    |
    P (pointer pointing to initial element of array)
```

when `3` gets added to pointer `P`, the resulting pointer will be pointing to 4<sup>th</sup> character:

```
  ----------------------------------------------
  | h | e | l | l | o | W | o | r | l | d | \0 |
  ----------------------------------------------
                ^
                |
                P (after adding 3 the resulting pointer pointing to 4th element of array)
```

This resulting pointer of expression `3+"helloWorld"` will be passed to `printf()`. Note that the first parameter of `printf()` is not array but pointer to a null-terminated string and the expression `3+"helloWorld"` resulting in pointer to `4th` element of `"helloWorld"` string. Hence, you are getting output `"loWorld"`.

Answer (score 2):

The answers from dbush and haccks are concise and illuminating, and I upvoted the one from haccks in support of the bounty offered by dbush.

The only thing that I find left unsaid is that the way the question title is phrased makes me wonder if the OP would think that e.g. this also should produce an error:

```
char sometext[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
printf (sometext);
```

since there is no string literal involved at all.  The OP needs to understand that one should never think that a function call that takes a `char *` argument can "only allow taking a string literal as [that] argument".

The answers from dbush and haccks hint at this by mentioning the conversion of a string literal to a `char *` (and how adding an integer to that evaluates), but I feel that it's worth pointing out explicitly that **anything** that is treated as a `char *` can be used, even things *not* converted from a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `printf` is declared as `const char *format`. It means `printf` should be passed a pointer to `char` and the characters pointed to by this pointer will not be changed by `printf`. There are additional constraints on this first argument:

- it should point to a proper C string, that is an array of characters terminated by a null byte.
- it may contain conversion specifiers, which must be properly constructed and the corresponding arguments must be passed as extra arguments to `printf`, with the expected types and order as derived from the format string.

Passing a string constant such as `"helloWorld"` as the format argument is the most common way to invoke `printf`. String constants are arrays of `char` terminated by a null byte which should not be modified by the program. Passing them to functions expecting a pointer to `char` will cause a pointer to their first byte to be passed, as is the case for all arrays in C.

The expression `"helloWorld" + 3` or `3 + "helloWorld"` evaluates to a pointer to the 4th byte of the string. It is equivalent to the expression `3 + &("helloWorld"[0])`, `&("helloWorld"[3])` or simply `&"helloWorld"[3]`. As a matter of fact, it is also equivalent to `&3["helloWorld"]` but this latest form is only used for pathological obfuscation.

`printf` does not use the bytes that precede the `format` argument, so passing `3 + "helloWorld"` is equivalent to passing `"loWorld"` and produces the same output.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf(3+"helloWorld"); //Output is "loWorld"
```

It will not give error because String in C Language String is array of characters and Array name give base address of array.
In case of **printf(3+"helloWorld")**;
 **3+"helloWorld"** is giving the address of fourth element of array of charecters i.e  of String

This is still a valid pointer to a string i.e char*

```
printf only allow taking a char* as the first argument
```

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise, the first argument to `printf()` function is not an array of chars but a pointer to array of chars. the difference between them is the same difference between `byval` and `byref` in VB world. 
a pointer can be incremented and decremented using (++ and --) or applying arithmetic operations (+ and -).

in your case you are passing a pointer to "helloWorld" incremented by three, thus it points to the forth element of the array of chars "helloWorld".

lets simplify this in asm  pseudo code

```
MOV EAX, offset ("helloWorld")
ADD EAX, 3
PUSH EAX
CALL printf
```

you maybe think that `3+"hello word"` do concatenation between 3 and "hello world", but in C concatenation is done otherwise. the simplest way to do is `sprintf(buff, "%d%s",3,"hello wrord");`

Answer (score -1):

It's pretty strange, but not wrong. By doing `3 +` you are moving your pointer to a different location.

The same thing work when you initialize a `char *`:

```
char *str1 = "Hello"; 
char *str2 = 2 + str1;
```

`str2` is now equal to `"llo"`.

Comment: It is confusing to write *`str2` is now equal to `"llo"`*. `str2` is a pointer, it points to a C string `"llo"`.